# How can I use QMenuBar to switch between widgets?

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

I don't know much about QT. I am trying to do my first GUI and actually this is the first thing that I want to do.

How can I set up top menu bar to switch between layouts? Again, I don't know yet how to even set up these layouts and I don't know the jargon to name the things theirs names, but I'll get to it.. I hope.

Actually, Windows has this type of windows all over the system. Can I make one of these myself?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt has a [QtabWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) that has its own layout on every tab, so you dont need to define anything, qt handle t runtime the display of the layout associated to every tab